# How do you debug a series of Aspect in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

I've got a chain of aspects that are being executed in some cases but not in others.  The stack typically looks something like this w/o giving an context information.  There doesn't appear to be any logging that I can enable either.  Thanks for any help on this.

```
GeneratedMethodAccessor163.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: not available 
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 585  
AspectJAroundAdvice(AbstractAspectJAdvice).invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(Object[]) line: 566  
AspectJAroundAdvice(AbstractAspectJAdvice).invokeAdviceMethod(JoinPoint, JoinPointMatch, Object, Throwable) line: 556   
AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 57   
Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation(ReflectiveMethodInvocation).proceed() line: 173    
ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 89   
Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation(ReflectiveMethodInvocation).proceed() line: 185    
Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Object, Method, Object[], MethodProxy) line: 652
```

Comment: Actually it appears that we have a circular dependency in the advice which is causing the advices to fail being created.  Unfortunately the message showing this is on debug level.  doh! double doh!

Answer (score 2):

You can step through aspects in a debugger if you've installed the [AspectJ Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/) (AJDT), a plugin for eclipse.